# Too much boilerplate, how can I reduce my POJO builders?

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, builder, pojo

I have several different [POJOs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) that use a [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), but after adding a builder for each one and generating `Object.toString`, `Object.hashCode` and `Object.equals`, my classes end up being around 100 lines of code. There has to be a better way to handle this. I think having some sort of a  reflective builder would help out a lot, but I'm not sure this would be good practice and I'm also not sure how I'd exactly make it happen. In other words, is there a way to implement a builder like this?

A simple POJO:

```
public class Foo {

    public int id;
    public String title;
    public boolean change;
    ...

}
```

Then some sort of reflective builder:

```
Foo = ReflectiveBuilder.from(Foo.class).id(1).title("title").change(false).build();
```

Comment: Are you using Apache commons for toString hashCode and equals? It's still a pain, but will save you a lot of time. You code have a base class that reflectively does toString, equals and hashCode then derive all your POJOs from that

Comment: @Leon I do, actually. But each class will still end up being 70-100 lines of code from each builder. There has to be a better pattern I'm just not aware of or a way to implement a reflective builder, at least that's how I feel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer **no**. What you ask for is not possible. Reflection looks at the code at runtime and invokes methods dynamically, it cannot generate actual methods.

What you could do would be:

```
Foo foo = ReflectiveBuilder.from(Foo.class).
              set("id", 1).
              set("title", "title").
              build();
```

This has three **massive** problems:

1. the fields are `String`s - a typo causes a runtime error rather than a compile time one,
2. the values are `Object`s - the wrong type causes a runtime error rather than a compile time one, and
3. it would be much slower than the alternative as Reflection is very slow.

So a reflection based solution, whilst possible (see Apache Commons BeanUtils [`BeanMap`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanMap.html)) is not at all practical.

Long answer, if you're willing to allow some compile time magic, you can use [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/). The idea behind Lombok is to generate boilerplate code from annotations using the Java annotation preprocessor system.

The really magical thing is that all IDEs, well the big 3 at least, understand annotation preprocessing and code completion will still function correctly even though the code doesn't *really* exist.

In the case of a `POJO` with a `Builder` you can use [`@Data`](http://projectlombok.org/features/Data.html) and [`@Builder`](http://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Builder.html)

```
@Data
@Builder
public class Foo {

    public int id;
    public String title;
    public boolean change;
    ...

}
```

The `@Data` annotation will generate:

- a required arguments constructor (that takes all `final` fields),
- `equals` and `hashCode` methods that use all fields (can be configured with the [`@EqualsAndHashCode`](http://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode.html) annotation)
- a `toString` method on all fields (can be configured with the [`@ToString`](http://projectlombok.org/features/ToString.html) annotation and
- `public` getters and setters for all fields (can be configured using the [`@Getter` / `@Setter`](http://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html) annotations on fields).

The `@Builder` annotation will generate an inner class called `Builder` that can be instantiated using `Foo.builder()`.

Do make sure you configure the `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString` methods as if you have two classes with Lombok that have references to each other then you will end up with an infinite loop in the default case as both classes include the other in these methods.

There is also a new [configuration system](http://projectlombok.org/features/configuration.html) that allows you to use, for example, fluent setters so you can more of less do away with the builder if your POJO is mutable:

```
new Foo().setId(3).setTitle("title)...
```

For another approach you can look at [Aspect-oriented programming](http://projectlombok.org/features/configuration.html) (AOP) and [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/). AOP allows you do chop your classes up into "aspects" and then stick them together using certain rules using a pre-compiler.  For example you could implement exactly what Lombok does, using custom annotations and an aspect. This is a fairly advanced topic however, and might well be overkill.

Comment: I realized that `Gson` actually uses a very similar approach to deserialize an `Object`, in that it uses reflection to initialize each `Field`. A builder based on the same reflection implementation might not be such a bad idea. What do you think?

Comment: @buildpattern It's a terrible idea as I point out. GSON does this because it _has_ to. You lose compile time type safety, meaning that you can hit runtime errors at any point, and you lose speed. Don't use reflection unless you **absolutely** have to, and **never** to reduce boilerplate.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/features/index.html) (yes the website is ugly) is an option for you. Lombok injects code into your classes based on annotations.

With Lombok you use the `@Data` annotations to generated getters, setters, `toString()`, `hashCode()` and `equals()`:

```
@Data
public class Foo {
    public int id;
    public String title;
    public boolean change;
}
```

Have a look at the example on the [@Data documentation section](http://projectlombok.org/features/Data.html) to see the generated code.

Lombok also provides a `@Builder` that generates a builder for your class. But be aware that this is an experimental feature:

```
@Builder
public class Foo {
    public int id;
    public String title;
    public boolean change;
}
```

Now you can do:

```
Foo foo = Foo.builder()
  .id(123)
  .title("some title")
  .change(true)
  .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally use [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) website to create all the boilerplate code for the POJOs for me. All you need to do is to paste the JSON that you want to parse, and it will generate all the classes for you. Then I just use Retrofit to do the requests/caching/parsing of the information. [Here](https://github.com/isaacurbina/RetroFitApp) is an example of Retrofit and POJOs in my Github account.
I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I created a small library [CakeMold](https://github.com/hosuaby/CakeMold) to do fluent initialization of POJOs. It uses reflection, what is certainly not fast. But can be very helpful when need to write tests.

```
Person person = CakeMold.of(Person.class)
    .set("firstName", "Bob")
    .set("lastName", "SquarePants")
    .set("email", "sponge.bob@bikinibottom.io")
    .set("age", 22)
    .cook();
```